# Xdebug runs for all cli commands despite remote_autostart being disabled

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, xdebug

Without completely disabling Xdebug from the php.ini I'm currently unable to stop Xdebug from running for all cli commands. Previously I would toggle remote_autostart to enable if I needed to debug through cli. My problem is in particular causing issues with composer, effectively making it unrunnable. Composer claim that composer should restart without Xdebug running if they see it is running, this is supposedly fixed from composer version 1.3 forward, but I'm using composer 1.7.3.

This is running inside my alpine PHP-FPM docker container but that shouldn't really make a difference. This issue has previously been experienced by a co-worker inside vagrant too so I can get his environment details too if needed.

php.ini Xdebug settings which I set myself:

```
zend_extension=/var/www/html/xdebug/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
#xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=172.20.0.1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log=/srv/www/var/log/xdebug.log
```

`php -i | grep 'xdebug'` output:

```
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 172.20.0.1 => 172.20.0.1
xdebug.remote_log => /srv/www/var/log/xdebug.log => /srv/www/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 10000 => 10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 20 => 20
```

Docker cli bash variables:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM";
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker";
```

Xdebug log when making cli connection:

```
Log opened at 2018-11-08 10:53:30
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.20.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/
xdebug" fileuri="file:///srv/www/pi.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version
="7.1.23" protocol_version="1.0" appid="863" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version=
"2.6.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><
url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2
018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

Comment: 1) If you set `xdebug.remote_autostart=0`, will it work? 2) Please check the actual config (e.g. `php -i`) to see actual values. Maybe that option is set & you have another partial config file that it is used... 3) Have composer and other tools use PHP with different php.ini (`-c` parameter (I believe)) or some other way around...

Comment: Hi @LazyOne 1. xdebug.remote_autostart=0 makes no difference, and I've also checked my php_info() and confirmed that that is the default setting being used. 2. Yes I've checked php -i, good point though that I should use the full xdebug config from php.ini in my post, I'll update it after this comment. 3. If I'm going and creating/using a new php.ini just for composer I may as well just have an alias to disable xdebug, run composer, then enable xdebug instead, the issue here is that's just one use case. I have many data intensive cli commands which I run and I don't want to have to address...

Comment: ... these use cases on an individual basis. It defeats the point. The issue here is that Xdebug is behaving incorrectly, workarounds are what I'm hoping to avoid. Thanks for your help

Comment: I personally see nothing wrong in your `php -i` that could lead to debug session auto-startup. BTW -- what is `/srv/www/pi.php` file? Maybe it has some commands there that trigger xdebug session (e.g. `xdebug_break();` or alike)... No better ideas from me, except trying to reinstall Xdebug again (you are using stable 2.6.1 and not unstable 2.7)

Comment: @LazyOne `pi.php` is the php entrypoint to the webapps cli which is executed from a separate `pi` bash file which is what we execute from the terminal. Example: `./pi run-queue --help`. Nothing in there about Xdebug. Re-installing makes no difference, this is all in a docker image so it's 100% reproducible on any machine. However I of course couldn't give this out as it contains my company's source code. I could make a minimal example I could give out so anyone can reproduce but it would take a long time so I'm hoping to avoid it.

Comment: Nothing in the config as far as I can tell (this my local Windows machine -- diff lines only: https://postimg.cc/LY3py30G -- nothing susp). Maybe something in environment? What about another docker image? No other ideas, sorry.

Comment: @LazyOne This is only a recent issue so when I'm back at work on Monday I'll step back through commits to the projects docker/ directory and see if I can pinpoint the issue. It'll be something I implemented recently since I only brought in xdebug for cli this week.

Comment: Looks like it has always happened and I just didn't pick up on it until the end of last week. Going back to the first implementation of xdebug for cli and it has the same issue

Comment: Well ... no better ideas from my chair. Reported config looks fine. Could be some environment or a programmatic breakpoint (calling `xdebug_break()`) ... but without knowing the stuff, its just like pointing with a finger into an open sky. Last thoughts: will it work with another/simple code? Will it work if different docker image (base) will be taken (for a simple code to start with)? P.S. I've starred this question, would be interesting to know the final resolution.

Comment: @LazyOne I suspect the solution will be something utterly stupid (if I find the solution), I'll keep fiddling with it and hopefully something will turn up. If I do find a solution I'll tag you

Comment: @LazyOne found the reason, I'm going to try and fix it tomorrow, reason is at the bottom of this article https://www.larrykagan.com/xdebug-on-docker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Undocumented Behavior**

`XDEBUG_CONFIG` environment variable has the undesired effect of causing Xdebug to run on every execution as described at the bottom of this article. https://www.larrykagan.com/xdebug-on-docker/

For me the solution was just to stop using `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="ide=PHPSTORM"` as that setting is already in my ini anyway.